# How do I 100% disable the grid icon view in Finder on a Mac?

Tags: mac, finder

*Sometimes* when I open a new finder folder window, it appears as grid icons, which I have no option of changing.

[image]

First of all, why don't I have an option to change it (notice in this context there is no menu to change to list view)? Second of all, how do I completely disable ever seeing in grid icon view. I **never** want to see grid icons, I always want either a list or a set of columns (most likely columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable icon view, it will always be an option.

What you can do is determine a set of defaults for New Window.
Finder menu > Preferences  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>  can set which location will be default.
View Options  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  can set default view type.

You can always change view on the fly with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>1</kbd> ,  <kbd>2</kbd> ,  <kbd>3</kbd>  or  <kbd>4</kbd> .

[image]

Comment: Set a "default", because Finder always always _finds_ a way to use a different view regardless of how many defaults one sets